# Postback using WebClient and EventValidation

Tags: c#, session, screen-scraping, webclient, eventvalidation

There's a web page from one of our subsidiaries. The page has EventValidation turned on. I've tried grabbing it and passing it as a postback value, but that doesn't work (obviously). Any ideas (besides turning off EventValidation)? Does it have anything to do with the session? By calling the WebClient on two separate calls, am I killing off my session?

**Update**: I'd prefer to use c#.

Comment: You should probably mention the language you're using and tag your question appropriately.

Comment: I really don't care what language. However, EventValidation is a .NET thing and so I'd prefer to use C#. Thanks.